# how to highlight a cube face on hover? THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, raycasting

I am using raycaster to define the face of a cube and then paint the face like this

```
const colorAttribute = intersected.object.geometry.getAttribute('color');
colorAttribute.setXYZ(face.a, color.r, color.g, color.b);
colorAttribute.setXYZ(face.b, color.r, color.g, color.b);
colorAttribute.setXYZ(face.c, color.r, color.g, color.b);
colorAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
```

But as you can see, the face is not completely painted over. Can someone help?
https://jsfiddle.net/kirill321592/fjdxpos1/43/

Comment: Hint: let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(); geometry = geometry.toNonIndexed();

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for the comment, but now the painted edge is divided into 2 even triangles

Comment: @WestLangley I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: Each face consists of two triangles, so you need to set the color of both. https://jsfiddle.net/zLt97pej/.  Another approach does not use vertex colors: `mesh = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, materials );` where `materials` is an array of 6 materials, one for each face.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it by clicking on the checkmark. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Each face consists of two triangles, so you need to set the color of both. jsfiddle.net/zLt97pej. Another approach does not use vertex colors: mesh = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, materials ); where materials is an array of 6 materials, one for each face. ty @WestLangle